# How to access a context of RESTAS submodules from other RESTAS modules

Tags: web, lisp, common-lisp, hunchentoot

Let's say, I define a dynamic variable `*a*` inside a module `m1`. Then I mount-module `m1` in a `m2` module:

```
(in-package m2)

(mount-module sub (#:m1)
   (m1:*a* 3))
```

How can I get the value 3 now from the module `m2`? For example, currently, I have to hack it in a such way:

```
(restas:with-context
    (second (gethash 'm1
                     (gethash
                       :modules
                       (gethash (find-package :m2)
                                restas::*pkgmodules-traits*))))
    m1:*a*))
```

Which is, certainly, not even close to a good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly better solution is the following:

```
(defmethod restas:module-context ((module symbol))
      (second (gethash module (restas::pkgmodule-traits-modules *package*))))
```

Then you can access the context for the module with `module-context`, for example:

```
(with-context (module-context 'sub)
  m1:*a*)
```

Or better yet:

```
(with-module 'sub
  m1:*a*)
```

Note that you use the name you used when mounting the module, not the name of the package you mounted.

UPDATE: The method I described has been added to RESTAS.

Comment: That's indeed better, but still relies on the internal function `restas::pkgmodule-traits-modules`. I guess the framework is not designed for such manipulations

Comment: The module-context method is now in RESTAS, so you no longer need to use pkgmodule-traits-modules directly.